# What are all codecs and formats supported by FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need a list of codecs and formats supported by FFmpeg. Where can I find it?

Comment: There should be a SE site for FFmpeg. Please [follow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40292) and verify your email to cast you vote!

Comment: My similar question got a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727992/ffmpeg-fourcc-avi-codec-support-list

Answer (score 239):

Codecs proper:

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

Formats:

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

Comment: That would only be a list of formats supported by a specific build/installation of FFmpeg.  There are a very wide range of FFmpeg builds in use.

Comment: Yes, if you're interested in it abstractly, you can consult the source code and broader documentation.  However, most people will initially be interested in *their* ffmpeg.

Comment: I guess it depends on the intent of the questioner, but I don't consider it abstract.  If a client calls and ask me to support the Purple Unicorn Codec 2.718, it wouldn't occur to me to do `ffmpeg -formats`.

Comment: FWIW, the "-codec" option is not available for ffmpeg version SVN-r0.5.10 and (presumably) earlier.

Comment: @Matthew Not necessarily... The main reason I am interested to see if a codec is supported is that I already got an "Unsupported codec" message from my ffprobe and want to see if this is due to my local installation....

Answer (score 161):

The [formats](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) and [codecs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html) supported by your build of `ffmpeg` can vary due the version, how it was compiled, and if any external libraries, such as libx264, were supported during compilation.

### Formats (muxers and demuxers):

List all formats:

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

Display options specific to, and information about, a particular muxer:

```
ffmpeg -h muxer=matroska
```

Display options specific to, and information about, a particular demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -h demuxer=gif
```

### Codecs (encoders and decoders):

List all codecs:

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

List all encoders:

```
ffmpeg -encoders
```

List all decoders:

```
ffmpeg -decoders
```

Display options specific to, and information about, a particular encoder:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=mpeg4
```

Display options specific to, and information about, a particular decoder:

```
ffmpeg -h decoder=aac
```

### Reading the results

There is a key near the top of the output that describes each letter that precedes the name of the format, encoder, decoder, or codec:

```
$ ffmpeg -encoders
[…]
Encoders:
 V..... = Video
 A..... = Audio
 S..... = Subtitle
 .F.... = Frame-level multithreading
 ..S... = Slice-level multithreading
 ...X.. = Codec is experimental
 ....B. = Supports draw_horiz_band
 .....D = Supports direct rendering method 1
 ------
[…]
 V.S... mpeg4                MPEG-4 part 2
```

In this example `V.S...` indicates that the encoder `mpeg4` is a `V`ideo encoder and supports `S`lice-level multithreading.

### Also see

[What is a codec and how does it differ from a format?](https://superuser.com/a/300997/110524)

Comment: Thank you very much llogan for those extra filtering options. Is it possible to further go, and for example ask FFMPEG to list all Encoders/Decoders that are only for Video, or only for Audio?

Comment: @spaceman You can do that with some additional processing. Example using `grep` on Linux: `ffmpeg -encoders | grep "^ V"`

Comment: Is there any way to list codecs available for each format?

Comment: @NickeManarin No, but you can view the default encoders for a muxer, such as with: `ffmpeg -h muxer=webm`

Answer (score 64):

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

should give you all the info about the codecs available.

You will see some letters next to the codecs:

```
Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 .....S = Lossless compression
```

Comment: Codecs, those DEVILS.

Answer (score 37):

You can see the list of supported codecs in the official documentation:

[Supported video codecs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Video-Codecs)

[Supported audio codecs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs)

Answer (score 1):

To list all pixel formats supported:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the source:

`libavformat/allformats.c`

`libavcodec/allcodecs.c`

Comment: Interesting solution. You can explore compatibility between version easily by navigating with branches.
`libavformat/allformats.c`: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/allformats.c
`libavcodec/allcodecs.c`: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/allcodecs.c