# ffmpeg / avconv on ubuntu invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, transpose, avconv

I have a .mp4 (h264) file on my ubuntu and try to rotate it using avconv (or ffmpeg, the result is the same). Actually, whatever action I'm trying to do with the file I get the "filename: invalid data found when processing input"

The interesting thing is when I try to rotate the same file using ffmpeg library on windows, it runs smoothly. Below is the actual command that runs on windows, but doesn't run on ubuntu

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile.mp4 -vf transpose=1 outputFile.mp4
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you

Ilija

Comment: The following doesn't works also:

`avconv -i inputVideo.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -vf "vflip" outputVideo.mp4`

and

`avconv -i inputVideo.mp4 -dir cclock outputVideo.mp4`

Comment: "Simplest possible example":  I bet that the problem still happens when you omit `-vf transpose=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's ffmpeg may lack codecs to parse inputFile.mp4.  On Windows, transcode inputFile.mp4 to a different format;  then, on Ubuntu, use the transcoded file as input.

Windows: `ffmpeg -i inputFile.mp4 -c:v something -c:a somethingElse transcoded.mp4`

Ubuntu: `ffmpeg -i transcoded.mp4 -vf transpose=1 outputFile.mp4`

[What are all codecs supported by FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377300/what-are-all-codecs-supported-by-ffmpeg)

(There's nothing special about either Ubuntu or Windows here.  It's just a particular installation of ffmpeg, unable to read a particular input.)

Comment: ffmepg -formats returns 

E ipod            iPod H.264 MP4 format

Comment: Then replace `something` with `h264`, and `somethingElse` with (say) `wav`.

Comment: Sorry Camille, but it didn't help. Finally I built the tool and windows, so it works great there