# List of FFMPEG audio formats and their file extensions

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, file-extension

I've tried to find information about this but to no avail.

What audio formats and their file extensions are supported by FFMPEG?

Is there a command that can list them all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all codecs and formats supported by FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377300/what-are-all-codecs-and-formats-supported-by-ffmpeg)

Comment: Unfortunately not. That was actually the last thing I read before asking my question. I need to figure out and get a list of only the audio file formats that FFMPEG can read.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no list with extensions.
However you can look up common extensions per muxer.

1. List all codecs. You can narrow it down with selecting only `DEA` (`D`ecoding supported, `E`ncoding supported, `A`udio codec)

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -codecs | grep DEA`

Now you get a long list.

Take e.g. `DEA.LS dts         DCA (DTS Coherent Acoustics) (decoders: dca ) (encoders: dca )`

1. Now query the common extensions for `dts`:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -h muxer=dts`

Result: `Common extensions: dts.`

(With other codecs you should also try `demuxer=`)

Comment: I have tried that already, but It's not a reliable solution :/